# Loop for custom attr

Tags: jquery, loops, attr

I'm looking for a loop that will count like that

```
1 , 0.8 , 0.6, 0.4 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.4 , 0.6 , 0.8 , 1
```

and append to custom attr `"data-depth"` with `li` element `i` got so far something like that and I cant move on

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $tiles.eq(i).attr('data-depth', -(i*0.2-1));
}
```

then it return first part `"1 , 0.8 , 0.6, 0.4 , 0.2 "`

Anyone can help me?

Comment: whats exactly the problem?

Comment: It's really confusing how you're trying to relate your loop and the 'depth' computation.  Maybe add your html as well?

Comment: Does it need to continue to repeat? Or just go down and up?

Comment: @emragins dude there is no html - read properly please, there is ul li and to many of them set attr.

Comment: @Jason I'd like to count from 1-0,2 and 0,2-1 and so on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A repeating version...

http://jsfiddle.net/2wb9koec/1/

```
var count = 0;
var i = 1.2;
var ul = jQuery("ul");
var step = -0.2;

while(count<50) {
    if(i===0.2) {
        if(step<0) {
            i = 0;
            step = 0.2;
        }
    } else if(i>=1) {
        if(step>0) {
            i = 1.2;
            step = -0.2
        }
    }

    i = Math.round((i+step)*100)/100;

    ul.append("<li>"+i+"</li>");

    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to go down till 0.2 and up from there on. Check the demo below which uses a direction to increment after reaching the limit.

**Note:** You may need to update the iterate count and increment as you need.

```js
var direction = -1, initValue = 1.0, limit = 0.2;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (initValue.toFixed(2) < limit) {
        initValue = limit;
        direction = 1;
    }    
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '<p>' + initValue.toFixed(2) +'</p>';
    initValue = initValue + (0.2 * direction);
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: First time trying out the code snippet and I am loving it.